# Where to configure a WCF service (REST and SOAP)

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, web-config, global-asax

I am implementing a WCF Web Service responsible of publishing data via REST and SOAP by using multiple bindings. The service is to be hosted on an IIS.

I have previously written some WCF services and know a bit about configuring those by using the web.config and setting up routes in the Global.asax files, however I'm confused about how to make the most "clean" configuration or the best practice on configuring a WCF service.

Here's what I have figured so far:

The web.config can be used to setup bindings, endpoints, security etc - is this needed when hosting the service on IIS or can the configuration be done on the IIS?

By using the Global.asax we're able to configure routings (and lots of other stuff). but is it the right place to do this?

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Service", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(Service)));
    }
```

I've spent some time googling this topic and it seems that every link has it's own opinion on how to accomplish the task.

Therefore I would like some input on how to configure/implement a WCF service to support the following:

- Publish the data via REST/JSON *and*
- Pubish the data via SOAP/XML and publishing metadata
- Provide to different services; http://domain.com/Service and http://domain.com/AuthService

For the record I'm aware of how to publish the data using both SOAP/REST - that's not the problem. I'm just trying to make to most clean/minimal configuration for the service.

Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how I've done this.

Web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="Service">
            <endpoint address="soap" contract="IService" binding="basicHttpBinding"/>
            <endpoint address="rest" contract="IService" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior"/>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="restBehavior">
                <webHttp/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

The contract looks like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate="/Update/{id}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    void Update(string id, Entity entity);
}
```

Comment: And how would you make a request?
http://localhost:port/Service/Update/1 ?
I'm asking because I just tried with you suggestion and I'm only able to reach the service at http://localhost:port/Service1.svc and not by using /Service/Update/1

Comment: For a SOAP client the URL is localhost:port/Service.svc/soap. For a REST one it is localhost:port/Service.svc/rest/Update/1. My answer is about how one can minimally configure two endpoints. If you need that exact URL then some additional configuration is needed.

Comment: I need to be able to configure to services located on 2 different urls: http://domain.com/Service and http://domain.com/AuthService

Comment: I partly used your suggestion so I'm accepting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

With .net 4.5 you can omit any configuration in .config file at all.  [ServiceContract], [OperationContract], [DataContract] would be essential. They do not say that in documentation explicitly, but it works :)

".NET Framework 4.5 makes configuring a WCF service easier by removing the requirement for the **service** element. If you do not add a **service** section or add any endpoints in a **service** section and your service does not programmatically define any endpoints, then a set of default endpoints are automatically added to your service, one for each service base address and for each contract implemented by your service." - from

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358768%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396